# (R shiny) cannot change the width of infoBox

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I use the library shinydashboard to write my ui.R. In my dashboardBody part, I wrote:

```
fluidRow(infoBoxOutput("dri"))
```

And then in my server.R, I wrote:

```
output$dri = renderInfoBox({
    infoBox(
        width = 2,
        title = tags$b("Score"),
        value = tags$b("100"),
        color = "aqua",
        fill = TRUE,
        icon = icon("edit")
    )
})*
```

But the width won't change to 2; it still uses the default one, i.e. 4 (1/3 of the whole webpage width). 
Would someone help me with this? Thank you very much!

Comment: Is your `infoBox` in a column-based or row-based layout?

Answer (score 9):

Maybe you can `style` it yourself

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(fluidRow(infoBoxOutput("dri")),tags$style("#dri {width:200px;}"))
)

server <- function(input, output) { 
  output$dri <- renderInfoBox({
    infoBox(
      title = tags$b("Score"),
      value = tags$b("100"),
      color = "aqua",
      fill = TRUE,
      icon = icon("edit")
    )    
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**200 px**
[image]

**1000px**
[image]

Comment: @XinWang http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

I found this answer on github and it worked for me aswell:

> Instead of using **renderInfoBox** and **infoBoxOutput**, you can use **renderUI**
>   and **uiOutput** and that worked for me. This makes me think there is an
>   issue with the renderInfoBox function.